# First-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have problem with one equation, can someone help me with it? Thanks a lot!
Here it is:

$$\dfrac{\tan(y)}{\cos^2(y)}y'+\dfrac{\tan(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=0$$

Have a nice day/night!

Comment: Is y a function of x, g, or t?

Comment: Hello. There's y(x) prob.

Comment: Joe it's a derivative on the left You can rewrite it

Answer (score 2):

This is a separable equation. We have $$\frac{\tan y}{\cos^2y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{\tan x}{\cos^2x}$$
or $$\begin{align}
\frac{\tan y}{\cos^2y}\mathrm{d}y&=-\frac{\tan x}{\cos^2x}\mathrm{d}x\\
\int\frac{\tan y}{\cos^2y}\mathrm{d}y&=-\int\frac{\tan x}{\cos^2x}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
Can you continue from here?

**EDIT:** Here is the solution, as requested.
$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{\tan x}{\cos^2x}\mathrm{d}x&= \int\frac{\sin x}{\cos^3x}\mathrm{d}x \\
&=-\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^3}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2x+C\\
\frac{1}{2}\sec^2y&=-\frac{1}{2}\sec^2x+C\\
\cos^2x&=-\cos^2y+C\cos^2x\cos^2y \\
\cos^2y&=\frac{\cos^2x}{C\cos^2x-1} \\
y&=\arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2x}{C\cos^2x-1}}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: That was my first idea, but then I have sth like:  $y=\sqrt(arccos(cos^2x+c))$ Is it correct?

Comment: If the OP uses $\tan(x)$ to denote the tangent, please do not switch notations in your answer.

Comment: @Adrain Keister he just changed it, he originally used $tg(x)$. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Joe I did not get that.

Comment: I'm new, I don't know how I chaned it, but it's true, first time I used tg(x).

Comment: @Tesseract: Understood. I've seen $\operatorname{tg}(x)$ for tangent, but EXTREMELY rarely. I can't say I like it. You can use `\operatorname` to make any text you want look like the `sin` in $\sin(x),$ by the way. It's a good way to go, because it preserves the right distances between symbols in $\LaTeX.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Agreed. I normally use that, but as you can see, $\tg$ doesn't render right.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thx for help. Also, can someone tell me about solution, is it good what I wrote somewhere below?

Answer (score 1):

**Another hint:**
$$\dfrac{\tan(y)}{\cos^2(y)}y'=\frac 1 2(\tan^2(y))'$$
And also :
$$\dfrac{\tan(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac 1 2 (\tan^2(x))'$$

Answer (score 0):

Thx for answers. I have sth like: $y=\sqrt{arccos(-cos2x+c)}$. Is it correct?

Comment: I don't think so; I added an edit to my answer. Check it out.